# How does $A = P\cdot (1+r)^{n}$ becomes a graph function of $A = P\cdot (1+rt)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Accumulated simple interest function is:

$A = P\cdot (1+rt)$

When I tried to graph it, it fails.

After I read some articles, it tells that to graph simple interest function is a different equation:

$A = P\cdot (1+r)^{n}$

where $A$ is on Y-axis and $n$ is on X-axis.

And it works.

My question is:

How to find out a graph function from a function?

Comment: What are the axis of the graph? To be clear: You want to graph $A=P\cdot (1+rt)$?

Comment: Sir, here is the link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s7hzamxyuf

Comment: So you want to graph $A=P\cdot (1+r)^n$? I'm confused a little bit.

Comment: My question is if we try to graph from =⋅(1+), it does not work correctly. I want to sketch a graph from the function. I found that someone said graph function for this function is =⋅(1+)^ but I don't know how he got its graph formula.

Comment: If you want to graph $A=P(1+rt)$ you multiply out the brackets first. $A(t)=P+Prt$. Here t is on the x-axis and A on the y-axis. This is a linear function with the slope $Pr$ and the intercept $P$

Comment: The first formula is used for simple interest, whereas the second formula is used for compound interest.

Comment: @NaySie Any further questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to graph $A=P(1+rt)$ you multiply out the brackets first. $A(t)=P+Pr\cdot t$. Here t is on the $x$-axis and A on the $y$-axis. This is a linear function with the slope Pr and the intercept $P$.

I have added the linear function (simple interest) to your graph.

[image]